# Do I need to call 'CGPathRelease' manually in OC?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, cgpath

Suppose that I get the current context in 'drawRect:rect' method and create a path. What will this path be after calling 'CGContextDrawPath' method?
Will it be released safely or cause memory leak, or just remain the same? Do I need to call 'CGPathRelease' manually

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 20, 50);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 20, 100);

CGContextAddPath(context, path);

//Do something else here 

CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to call CGPathRelease manually. Remember ARC **does not manage** Core Foundation objects. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html) is some reading material